# iText 2.1.7 insert rows dynamically into any existing table in PDF form

Tags: itext

I have a pdf form that i read and update the fields in it using

```
    getAcroFields(). 
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    form.setField("Name", "Jim");
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

In that same pdf form i have a table whose fields also i update. On top of that i need to insert more rows to that table only if needed. The rows to be added are between two rows and not at the end. How do i insert rows to an existing table which has fields that i am  updating already using getAcroFields().

Any ideas please? Worst case how to add at the end.

Comment: So basically you just want to target a specific table and insert a variable amount of rows to it based on some condition and insert those rows somewhere in the middle of the table. What's the problem? If you want us to write it for you, show us the table, a sample of some of your dynamically generated rows and the index of the table you'd like to insert them at.

Comment: My table will have 5 columns and 6 rows. 5th row is dynamic one. it could be 0 to many. Already each cell in the table is a form field, i am fetching them using getAcroFields() and updating the value.    reader = new PdfReader("C:\\temp.pdf");
stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream(path));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.setField("option1", "xxxx");
form.setField("option2", "yyyy");
form.setField("option3", “wwww");
form.setField("option4", "lllll");
……….
Insert dynamic table here – how?
stamper.close();
reader.close();